# MariaDB/MySQL str_to_date format with timezone offset

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, mariadb

### Edit: TL;DR

```sql
# This query ---------------------------------------

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2020-10-20T14:43:49+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') AS date;

# Results in----------------------------------------

+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2020-10-20 14:43:49 |
+---------------------+

# But throws----------------------------------------

+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-10-20T14:43:49+00:00' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why?

### Detailed description

I have read through a lot of questions regarding similar issues, but could not find a definitive answer to this problem.

I'm running Doctrine migrations in a Symfony 5.2.x project on a MariaDB 10.2 database. I am trying to extract a date string from a JSON data column into its own column on the same table, but running into error messages when the original date string has a certain format.

```sql
ALTER TABLE form 
  ADD updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;

UPDATE form AS f 
  SET updated_at = STR_TO_DATE(
    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM (
      SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.updatedAt')
    )), 
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+00:00'
  );
```

This works for any date string with a timezone offset of 0, like `2020-12-04T11:14:07+00:00`. For obvious reasons, it fails for a non-zero offset like `2020-12-04T11:14:07+01:00`, because

> Literal characters in *format* must match literally in *str*.
>
> -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

and results in an error

```
Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2020-12-04T11:14:07+01:00' for function str_to_date
```

**However**, if I understand the documentation correctly, I shouldn't even have to include the timezone offset in the format string:

> Extra characters at the end of *str* are ignored.

But when I change the format string from `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+00:00'` to `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'`, the update operation fails for ***all*** items, even though the dates are parsed correctly (or, at least, *look* correct):

```sql
MariaDB [db]> select STR_TO_DATE('2020-10-20T14:43:49+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') as date;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2020-10-20 14:43:49 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [db]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-10-20T14:43:49+00:00' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### The Question

Apart from the historic bug in the application that would in some cases result in a non-UTC `updated_at` date, **what am I doing wrong**? As I understand it, anything in the string after the bit matching `%s` should be ignored by `STR_TO_DATE()` and irrelevant to the query. Why are my migrations failing when the DB clearly manages to parse the strings to something that looks like the `datetime` type it understands? How can I make sure it parses every item's date irrespective of its TZ offset (I wouldn't even mind if the result was updated_at times for some items with an hour's difference to the actual datetime)?

### Edit

Because I don't fully understand what it does or what the implications are, I've tried changing `sql_mode` before executing my queries, but got the same results:

```sql
SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE', '');
SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
```

### Edit II

I ended up rewriting the migration and manually looping over each entry in PHP, re-setting the timezone and writing the corrected (UTC) value back to the DB.
This is obviously way more verbose and much slower than the SQL one-liner. The lack of answers (or even comments) here suggests I might have stumbled upon either a Maria/MySQL bug or faulty documentation.